# Croppie returns black images after cropping

Tags: javascript, cropperjs, croppie

I am working on a project in which I want to implement croppie js with modal. For that i found a codepen which suits my requirement. But the problem is that after performing crop the resulted image is black.

Can anyone help me with this. The link of the codepen is provided below: https://codepen.io/asrulnurrahim/pen/WOyzxy

```js
// Start upload preview image
$(".gambar").attr("src", "https://user.gadjian.com/static/images/personnel_boy.png");
                        var $uploadCrop,
                        tempFilename,
                        rawImg,
                        imageId;
                        function readFile(input) {
                            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                              var reader = new FileReader();
                                reader.onload = function (e) {
                                    $('.upload-demo').addClass('ready');
                                    $('#cropImagePop').modal('show');
                                    rawImg = e.target.result;
                                }
                                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                            }
                            else {
                                swal("Sorry - you're browser doesn't support the FileReader API");
                            }
                        }

                        $uploadCrop = $('#upload-demo').croppie({
                            viewport: {
                                width: 150,
                                height: 200,
                            },
                            enforceBoundary: false,
                            enableExif: true
                        });
                        $('#cropImagePop').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
                            // alert('Shown pop');
                            $uploadCrop.croppie('bind', {
                                url: rawImg
                            }).then(function(){
                                console.log('jQuery bind complete');
                            });
                        });

                        $('.item-img').on('change', function () { imageId = $(this).data('id'); tempFilename = $(this).val();
                                                                                                         $('#cancelCropBtn').data('id', imageId); readFile(this); });
                        $('#cropImageBtn').on('click', function (ev) {
                            $uploadCrop.croppie('result', {
                                type: 'base64',
                                format: 'jpeg',
                                size: {width: 150, height: 200}
                            }).then(function (resp) {
                                $('#item-img-output').attr('src', resp);
                                $('#cropImagePop').modal('hide');
                            });
                        });
                // End upload preview image
```

```css
label.cabinet{
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

label.cabinet input.file{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0);
  margin-top:-30px;
}

#upload-demo{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
  padding-bottom:25px;
}
figure figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/croppie.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/croppie.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <label class="cabinet center-block">
                                        <figure>
                                            <img src="" class="gambar img-responsive img-thumbnail" id="item-img-output" />
                                          <figcaption><i class="fa fa-camera"></i></figcaption>
                                    </figure>
                                        <input type="file" class="item-img file center-block" name="file_photo"/>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="cropImagePop" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                          <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                                <?=multiLanguage( "Edit Foto" , "Edit Photo" )?></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="upload-demo" class="center-block"></div>
                      </div>
                             <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" id="cropImageBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Crop</button>
      </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```